# Turning this JSON into an accessible Java Object

Tags: java

The JSON file/data/string that I need to convert:

```json
{
    "title": "Application Title <You may change the title of your app>",
    "description": "This is an inventory for company system information",
    "systems": [ 
        {
            "name": "string",
        "purpose": "string",
            "owner": "string",
            "sub_owner": ["string", "string"],
            "location": "string",
        "tag": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "string" 
            "purpose": "string",
            "owner": "string",
            "sub_owner": ["string", "string"],
            "location": "string",
        "tag": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am currently using GSON library, and I am still trying to map again the nested objects/list/arrays inside so I can access a specific key inside to edit or change that value. Here's where I'm stuck right now:

```
jsonData = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Java/system.json")));
Map<String, Object> outerData = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType());
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> outerList : outerData.entrySet()){
  System.out.print(outerList.getKey() + ": " + outerList.getValue() + "\n");
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gson has a generic "tree" representation just like Jackson has. However, it might be easier if you'd represent that json using pojos. How would you represent that data as plain java objects?

Comment: Why do you parse to `Map` and not to a custom class?

Comment: this is my first time with java, so i really don't have much regarding java

Comment: There are several approaches to this but if you're just starting with Java, you may also consider Groovy, which is very similar to Java but dynamic. With Groovy you can map a JSON directly to a compatible object.

Comment: im actually required to use java, so i currently have no choice on how to go about this.

Comment: [Read This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generate-class-from-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.2)'s ObjectMapper.

You must declare your objects to match the structure of the JSON.

```
public class Foo {

    private String title;
    private String description;
    private List<System> systems;

    // standard getters setters
}


public class System {

    private String name;
    private String purpose;
    private String owner;
    private List<String> sub_owner; //or subOwner, depending on ObjectMapper's configuration
    private String location;
    private String tag;

    // standard getters setters
}
```

And then you can do:

```
String jsonData = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("Java/system.json")));
Foo foo = objectMapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```